# Error while updating values in grid view

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, view, grid

Update Command

```
UPDATE [raw_master] 
SET [itemname] = ?, 
    [spec1] = ?, [spec2] = ?, 
    [ucode] = ?, [rate] = ?, 
    [stock] = ?, [minstock] = ?, 
    [maxstock] = ?, [rol] = ?, 
    [lcode] = ? 
WHERE 
    (([icode] = ?) OR ([icode] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL)) 
    AND (([itemcode] = ?) OR ([itemcode] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL))
```

It is an auto-generated query.

Error thrown:

> No value was given for one required parameter

Note:

When all the columns in my table are declared as `string`, it's working fine, but if there is a column with a data type `int32`, the above error is thrown

Comment: If you don't add the code that calls this UPDATE there is no way to tell you which parameter is missing

Comment: Are you using a SqlDataSource for the data source of gridview?

Comment: Yes @Sunil SqlDataSource

Answer (score 0):

The code worked when I removed (field IS NULL AND ? IS NULL) validation. Why is this happening?